# Open Wi-Fi networks - Check connection in android

Tags: java, android, networking, connection, wifi

You might know the open Wi-Fi networks where you have to enter a password to use the internet. These are often in an airport. If you have enabled Wi-Fi your device connects to this network. Now I would like to send data with an app. 
So I have to check if there is a Wi-Fi network which I can use to send the data. I guess that these open networks at the airport do not allow to send data. If there is no network the device would connect via mobile data. 
So how can I check if it is possible to send data via Wi-Fi?

Comment: Er, if WiFi doesn't send data, what does it do?

Comment: I thought so. Because i can not connect to internet and use apps like Whatsapp.

Comment: networks that filter apps uses firewalls, there are way too many filtering techniques used by firewalls (web only, application ...).
so you need to know exactly what you're dealing with before looking for a solution ...

Comment: You are right. I found out that some networks block ports of Instant Messenger. The data are sent as a HTTP request. Should the code posted by Jashaszun work? I just need to know if a HTTP request works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you just need to check if you have Wi-Fi, since if you have Wi-Fi, you can send data through it. You check it like this:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (wifi.isConnected())
{
    // send your data
}
```

Comment: Apps like Whatsapp did not work in those networks which were open in the airport. Does it also work with those networks? Because there seems to be a gate. I have to check it with these networks.